# Spring Cloud Stream Event Routing Bindings

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-stream

I've been developing a Event Driven Microservice, and I'm getting my head around some great Spring Cloud Function/Streams.

One thing I've had some difficulty with is Event Routing, and I was hoping someone might be able to shine a light on it.

I have in the `application.yaml` the following for the function configs:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: supplier;processA;processB;processC;functionRouter;
    stream:
      bindings:
        supplier-out-0:
          destination: process-event
        processA-in-0:
          destination: process-event
        processB-out-0:
          destination: route-event
        functionRouter-in-0:
          destination: route-event
        processC-out-0:
          destination: process-event
      source: processC
```

### Example class code

Provided to help illustrate where I might be wrong/confused.

#### Supplier.class

Polled at an interval

```java
@Component("supplier")
public class Supplier implements Supplier<PojoObj>
{

    @Override
    public NewBlockEvent get() {
        PojoObj pojoObj = new PojoObj();
        //...various checks
        return pojoObj;
    }
}
```

#### ProccessA.class

Function that is called by spring cloud due to binding destination/inputs and using Message Header/RouterFunction send it to either `processC`|| `processB`.

**Question 1**
Do I need to configure functions definitions in the `application.yaml` for `proccessB` & `proccessC` or will they be called/wrapper by the function router?

```java
@Component("processA")
public class ProcessA implements Function<PojoObj, Message<PojoObj>>
{

    @Override
    public Message<PojoObj> apply(PojoObj pojoObj) {
        String headerFunction = (pojoObj.needsMoreProcessing)?"processC":"processB";
        //...various checks
        MessageBuilder<PojoObj> tMessageBuilder = 
                    messageBuilder.withPayload(pojoObj);
        tMessageBuilder
                .setHeader("spring.cloud.function.definition", headerFunction);
        return tMessageBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

#### ProcessB.class

Function that is called before sending event out of Micro Service.

**Question 2**
Do I need a binding for the output of `processB` or is it that the output will be routed through the `funtionRouting-out-0` binding?

```java
@Component("processB")
public class ProcessB implements Function<PojoObj, PojoObj>
{

    @Override
    public PojoObj apply(PojoObj pojoObj) {
        //...various checks
        return pojoObj;
    }
}
```

#### ProcessC.class

Consumer that is called for more processing of the data before being sent out of the Micro Service. Using a `StreamBridge` it sends data to `processB` for last checks.

**Question 3**
Does this still use/create the `functionRouter-out-0` binding for the Consumer `ProcessB`? I have noticed in the output `Consumer does not have output type, returning null as output type.` so I'm also wondering if this is the right idea to use `StreamBridge`.

```java
@Component("processC")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ProcessC implements Consumer<PojoObj>
{
    private final StreamBridge streamBridge;

    @Override
    public PojoObj accept(PojoObj pojoObj) {
        //...various checks
        streamBridge.send("processC-out-0", pojoObj);
    }
}
```

First question so please let me know any improvements I can do or if more info is needed.